# How to trigger binding source update from code in WPF?

Tags: mvvm, drag-and-drop, binding

In My ViewModel class I have a property:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public string FileName {get;set;}
}
```

and in my `View` I bind a label's content to ViewModel's `FileName`.

now When I do drag-drop a file to my View, How can I update the label's `Content` property, so that the ViewMode's `FileName` also get updated via binding?

Directly set the label's `Content` property won't work, it just simply clear the binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to do it in code-behind, you can do something like that :

```
ViewModel vm = (ViewModel)this.DataContext;
vm.FileName = path;
```

(btw, your ViewModel class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`)

Comment: then the View will have to know about the ViewModel, is this anti-pattern?

Comment: I did implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Well, the view always knows about the ViewModel, since it has a reference to it (DataContext) and has bindings to its properties... If the ViewModel knew about the view, *then* you would be breaking the pattern